# Why i can't take address of variable?

Tags: c, variables

guys!
Why i can't take address of "t" - variable ?

```
flygs->type == 'X' ? t = a_ib_u(u->us, 16) : (a_lowcasealph(&(t = a_ib_u(u->us, 16))));
\\a_ib_u returns *char, a_lowcasealph take **char argument
```

error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'char *'

Comment: The result of an assignment isn't an *lvalue*. You can only take the address of lvalues. See e.g. [this value category reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category) for more information.

Comment: Please don't write ugly lines like this. If you split your code to multiple statements and lines, you run less frequently to weird and hard to solve issues.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks!

Comment: @user694733 ok,i'm student and i'm have some requirements for number of lines in my function,sry

Comment: "i'm have some requirements for number of lines in my function" - this is the sort of thing that should NOT be taught to students.  In the real world, working, easy to read and understand is the prime directive.  The sort of code you have written would not pass most code reviews.

Comment: ^^^^ in my office, it would get you fired.  Code like that sucks and, even in academia, should be frowned upon:(  It's difficult to understand, difficult to test and, most important difficult to debug.  It's just bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually taking the address of a variable here:

```
&(t = a_ib_u(u->us, 16))
```

What you have here is an expression which is the assignment operator, and whose value is the value assigned.  This is not the same as taking the address of a variable.  As was mentioned in the comments, a variable is an *lvalue*, while an expression involving one or more operators an *rvalue*.  You can only take the address of an lvalue.

To get around this, you can use the comma operator:

```
flygs->type == 'X' ? t = a_ib_u(u->us, 16) : 
                     a_lowcasealph(((t = a_ib_u(u->us, 16)), &t));
```

Note that you need an extra pair of parenthesis around the comma operator expression to prevent the comma from being interpreted as a separator for function arguments.

Comment: The resulting code hurts my eyes. Rewriting it, for example the way suggested in the answer by user 4386427, is preferrable.

Answer (score 5):

The answer by @dbush have already explained the cause of the error.

I like to add that you can rewrite the code and get something much easier to understand and maintain. Like:

```
t = a_ib_u(u->us, 16);
if (flygs->type != 'X') a_lowcasealph(&t);
```